# CastleWindsor BeginScope analog in Ninject

Tags: ninject, castle-windsor

I am using Scoped lifestyle for some dependencies in code with CastleWindsor and resolving them in scope like this:

```
  using (_container.BeginScope())
  {
      _implementation = _container.Resolve<IAbstration>();
  }
```

Does Ninject have analogs of such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built-in, but you can easily add this feature by creating a custom class that inherits from `DisposableObject`:

```
sealed class Scope : DisposableObject { }
```

You will have to store `Scope` instances on the active thread or async context, for instance using `AsyncLocal<T>`:

```
static readonly AsyncLocal<Scope> scopeProvider = new AsyncLocal<Scope>();
```

Now you can create your custom `BeginScope()` method that uses the `scopeProvider` as follows:

```
static Scope BeginScope() => scopeProvider.Value = new Scope();
```

Now you can implement your use case:

```
using (BeginScope())
{
    _implementation = _kernel.Get<IAbstration>();
}
```

Registering scoped instances can be done using the `InScope` method:

```
static Scope RequestScope(IContext context) => scopeProvider.Value;

void Configure() 
{
    IKernelConfiguration config = new KernelConfiguration();

    config.Bind<IUserService>().To<AspNetUserService>().InScope(RequestScope);
}
```